# Unsure about using partials in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

So I'm doing the railstutorial by Michael Hartl and am on Chapter 9. This bit of code is for pagination where render user renders a partial (named _user) with embedded ruby for the profile picture and user name

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All users</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= render user %>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

However this code is refactored into

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All users</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
  <%= render @users %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

My question now is how does Rails know to render the partial _user since there are no explicit instructions to do so? I've tried changing the name of the partial to figure out how, but I still don't know. For example I renamed the partial _users and it caused an error. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please read this part for [rendering collections](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It knows that the `@users` collection that you made is made up of instances of the class `User`, so when you call `render @users` in a view, it looks for a file called `_user.html.erb` and renders that file end to end for every `User` instance in the collection. Within the partial, you can access the iteration of the partial's corresponding `User` instance with `user`.

If you had a collection called `@my_collection` and it was made up of instances of the class `Howdy`, then `render @my_collection` would look for a partial named `_howdy.html.erb` and render it for every `Howdy` instance in `@my_collection`. The iteration of the partial's corresponding `Howdy` instance would be accessible as `howdy` within the partial.

Comment: ah perfect. Thank you.